# Can temporary workers in Australia enroll into the public health insurance system?

Tags: australia, health-insurance

Assuming one works in Australia on a 457 visa, can they access the public health insurance scheme? If not, can they get a refund of taxes paid for health insurance and social security?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a [temporary resident](https://www.ato.gov.au/individuals/medicare-levy/medicare-levy-exemption/category-3--not-entitled-to-medicare-benefits/) (a foreigner who is considered a resident for tax purposes), unless your country has a reciprocal​ agreement with Australia, you're not eligible to Medicare benefits, thus you can get a refund of your 2% Medicare levy at tax time.

Comment: But what if you're a tax resident in a given year? Temporary workers can stay for up to two years.

Comment: @JonathanReez I updated my answer with a link. As a temporary resident who is not entitled to Medicare you don't need to pay the 2% levy.